# Equintinuity of bounded linear functions equivalent to uniform boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

The claim is the following:

> Every family of bounded linear functions is equicontinuous if and only
>   it is uniformly bounded.

Equicontinuity is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity). Any suggestions about this?

I only have trouble figuring out the forward direction.

Comment: If $\|f\| \le M$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| \le M \|x-y\|$. Can you see how to do it now? And for the forward direction, I don't think you can use the uniform boundedness principle, because the conclusion of that theorem is that such a family is equicontinuous.

Comment: Yes! How did I miss that! What would be a way to go about it?

Comment: Try just using the definition of equicontinuity.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be very helpful.

Comment: By linearity, a family of operators is equicontinuous if they are equicontinuous at the origin. Perhaps this can help you.

Comment: Wouldn't that be helpful if we are trying to prove the reverse implication? For this one we are assuming that the family is equicontinuous. Using your comment, it would mean that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\|x\| < \delta \implies \|f(x)\| < \epsilon$. But how would one proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Suppose the family $F$ is bounded. Then there is $M > 0$ such that $\|f\| \le M$ for all $f \in F$, and hence by linearity $|f(x) - f(y)| = |f(x-y)| \le M \|x - y\|$. Thus we can choose $\delta = \epsilon /M$.
2. Suppose $F$ is equicontinuous. Then $F$ must be equicontinuous at the origin. Then, for every ball $B_{\epsilon}$, there exists $\delta$ such that $f(B_{\delta}) \subset B_{\epsilon}$ for every $f \in F$. In particular, if $S$ is the unit sphere, then $f(S) \subset B_{\epsilon/\delta}$. Then, by linearity, for any $x$, we have $f(x) \subset \|x\| B_{\epsilon/\delta}$, which is equivalent to $|f(x)| \le \epsilon/\delta \|x\|$.